# TLSharp. Отправка сообщения боту

Tags: c#, telegram, tlsharp

```
var dialogs = await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();                               
var chats = ((TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLDialogsSlice)dialogs).Users;

var tlChannel = chats.Where(_ => _.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
                                     .Select(_ => (TLUser)_)
                                     .Where(_ => _.Bot&&_.FirstName=="RedNeck")
                                     .FirstOrDefault();

await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser()
    { UserId = tlChannel.Id, AccessHash = (long)tlChannel.AccessHash },
                                "OUR_MESSAGE");
```

Как написать конкретному боту с помощью TLSharp? С проверкой на Username/FirstName/LastName(указывал как и просто имя, так и username из самого телеграмма) выдает ошибку что ничего не найдено(tlChannel было null), а без неё отправляет сообщение первому попавшемуся боту из диалогов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: (Восстание машин близко, боты друг с другом переписываются)